# Using Neo4j with PySpark on Databricks: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, neo4j, databricks

I am trying to query a graph hosted on Neo4j from Databricks using neo4j-spark-connector. I am using the following code to access the graph:

```
df = spark.read.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")\
 .option("url", "bolt://<IP adress>:7687")\
 .option("authentication.type", "basic")\
 .option("authentication.basic.username", "<username>")\
 .option("authentication.basic.password", "<password>")\
 .load()
```

This error is returned:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to 18.206.149.168:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
```

Any idea of what I am missing in the use of the connector here ?

**Details on versions/ libraries:**

Neo4j Browser version: 4.2.1-patch-3.0
Neo4j Server version: 4.4.8 (enterprise)

**Installed neo4j-spark-connector on Databricks:**

neo4j-contrib:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.0.1_for_spark_3

I have added in the spark configuration following lines:

```
spark.neo4j.bolt.password <password>
spark.databricks.passthrough.enabled true
spark.neo4j.bolt.url bolt://<IP adress>:7687
spark.neo4j.bolt.user <username>
```

Unfortunately, online [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/neo4j.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20connect%20a%20Databricks,and%20from%20the%20Neo4j%20server.) isn't up-to-date to latest releases of neo4j versions (4+).
I am trying to follow the process explained in this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-neo4j-with-pyspark-on-databricks-eb3d127f2245) by adapting it to the neo4j version I am using.

Comment: Does `%sh nc -vz 18.206.149.168 7687` shows that connection is successful?

Comment: Thank you for your repsonse,.`%sh nc -vz 18.206.149.168 7687` returns `nc: connect to 18.206.149.168 port 7687 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`. Do you have any idea why my connexion is refused ? I have "dbms.connector.bolt.enabled" set to True on Neo4J side btw.

Comment: For example, you have firewall somewhere in between…

Comment: You mean that Databricks has a firewall preventing me from getting access to neo4j ?Is there a way to disable it ?

Comment: No. DB doesn't have firewall by default. But your admins can put it somewhere